# WrappingUtils: Don't know how to round that drawable: com.facebook.drawee.drawable.RoundedColorDrawable？

Tags: android, react-native

[image]

error msg:

```
05-16 23:05:45.317 17513-17513/***.***.*** W/unknown:WrappingUtils: Don't know how to round that drawable: com.facebook.drawee.drawable.RoundedColorDrawable@1d3c24a1
05-16 23:05:45.320 17513-17513/***.***.*** W/unknown:WrappingUtils: Don't know how to round that drawable: com.facebook.drawee.drawable.RoundedColorDrawable@3b4ad6c6
05-16 23:05:45.321 17513-17513/***.***.*** W/unknown:WrappingUtils: Don't know how to round that drawable: com.facebook.drawee.drawable.RoundedColorDrawable@2f71f687
```

It keeps throwing errors message, May I ask why?

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: no at all.......

Comment: How did you bypass it? It's crashing my app on smaller versioned android phones.